# Center horizontally and vertically text in relative height div

Tags: html, css

I want to center my text in a relative height div which contains an image. I use absolute position but when my text is on two lines, the text is not centered. I've already tried to use a table but it doesn't work due to the `img`.

HTML:

```html
<div id="hubs">
  <h3>Nos Hubs</h3>
  <hr>
  <a class="thumbnail vignette-hub" href="http://kkw.fr">
    <img style="opacity: 0.6;filter: alpha(opacity=60);" alt="Aéroport de Nantes" src="http://kkw.fr/uploads/upload-center/nantes-vue-aerienne091501270208.png" width="100%" />
    <p class="txt-hub-image">
      Hub de</br>Nantes
    </p>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS :

```css
.txt-hub-image {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.vignette-hub {
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  min-width: 135px;
}
.thumbnail {
  display: block;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
}
.thumbnail > img,
.thumbnail a > img {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
a.thumbnail:hover,
a.thumbnail:focus,
a.thumbnail.active {
  border-color: #337ab7;
}
.thumbnail .caption {
  padding: 9px;
  color: #333;
}
```

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Have you looked at the various options mentioned here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically?

Comment: @Michael_B don't worry about that ;) I just see all the answers, I'm going to read all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few changes required to your snippet to make it automatically work for all dimensions:

- `p` tags by default have a `margin-top`. If you don't reset it, then absolutely positioning it at 50% would become 50% + `margin-top`. This needs to be reset.
- When you absolutely position an element at `top: 50%`, the box gets positioned at 50% height of the container and text keeps getting added from that position on. So, to match the center of the text block with the center of the parent, you have to translate the box with the text up by 50% of its own size. This can be done by adding `transform: translateY(-50%)`.
- You don't need to add a `height: 100%` on the `p` tag and it can be removed.

**Note:** Using `transform` method for positioning **needs CSS3 support** but I assume this shouldn't be a problem because you are already using `transition`. 
If you want to support non CSS3 compatible browsers, have a look at the other approaches mentioned [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically). I have added a different answer just to explain the first two points I had mentioned above.

```css
.txt-hub-image {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  /* added to fix the vertical centering */
  margin-top: 0px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.vignette-hub {
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  min-width: 135px;
}
.thumbnail {
  display: block;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
}
.thumbnail > img,
.thumbnail a > img {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
a.thumbnail:hover,
a.thumbnail:focus,
a.thumbnail.active {
  border-color: #337ab7;
}
.thumbnail .caption {
  padding: 9px;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div id="hubs">
  <h3>Nos Hubs</h3>
  <hr>
  <a class="thumbnail vignette-hub" href="http://kkw.fr">
    <img style="opacity: 0.6;filter: alpha(opacity=60);" alt="Aéroport de Nantes" src="http://kkw.fr/uploads/upload-center/nantes-vue-aerienne091501270208.png" width="100%" />
    <p class="txt-hub-image">
      Hub de</br>Nantes
    </p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Here is a [**demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/47abcf23/) as [the snippets feature seems to be down](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302099/stackoverflow-currently-offline-but-only-when-running-snippet?cb=1).

Comment: This is exactly what I would. For the non CSS3 browsers it's not a problem because my website is not provided for these old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Change your .txt-hub-image class, top value from 50% to 25%.